# Сравнение двух ответов в задаче про домино по теории вероятности

Tags: математика, комбинаторика, теория-вероятностей, вычислительный-эксперимент

Из полного набора костей домино (28 штук) наудачу достают 4 кости. Найдите вероятности событий:

- среди отобранных окажется ровно 1 кость с б очками:

решил двумя способами, ответы получились разными. Какой из них верный и почему?[image: Фотография с решением]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос никак не связан с тематикой сайта.

Comment: Конечно, второй. В первом не учтено, что кость может выпасть не только первой :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я увидел тэги с математикой и подумал, что можно и подобный вопрос здесь задать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтоб вопрос не закрывать, переведем его в другую плоскость: программисты мы или погулять вышли? :)

Вычислительный эксперимент - наше всё! :)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mt19937 g(random_device{}());
    vector<int> v;
    for(int i = 0; i < 28; ++i)
        if (i < 7) v.push_back(1);
        else v.push_back(0);
    int total = 0, ok = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    {
        shuffle(v.begin(),v.end(),g);
        if (v[0]+v[1]+v[2]+v[3] == 1) ++ok;
        ++total;
    }
    cout << double(ok)/total << endl;
}
```

И мы [сразу видим](https://ideone.com/rqzQTZ), что правильный ответ - второй.

Ну, а почему неверен первый? Потому что он у вас не учитывает, что кость с шестеркой может выпасть не только первой, а четырьмя способами.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, вы очень помогли, а то совсем уже забыл тервер